# Ошибка при sudo npm install?

Tags: linux, node.js, npm, fedora

установил fedora и node но немогу установить node_modules для работы с плагином gutenberg -https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg
npm 6.14.11
node 14.16.0
package.json говорит что npm < 7 версии должен быть
Есть ли кто то кто работает с gutenberg на fedora ? Помогите пожалуйста

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: 1. текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса. 2. разработчики так и написали: ["npm": ">=6.9.0 <7"](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/master/package.json#L19). ставьте npm требующейся версии или помогите адаптировать проект под более новую версию npm.

Comment: Понял , спасибо )

Comment: aleksandr barakin  , дело в том что у меня по версиях все сходится , npm у меня 6.14.11 , node 14.16.10